# Orthogonal complement of a vector bundle

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles

Let $E \rightarrow X$ be a vector bundle with an inner product. If $F$ is a sub-bundle, we can define an orthogonal complement bundle $F^\perp$ (see http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf for the construction, and the source of the problem). I am trying to show that $F^\perp$ is independent of the choice of inner product, up to isomorphism. I have tried to do a local construction, defining the isomorphism in each locally trivial neighborhood, but I do not see a way to patch these together into a global isomorphism. Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider two inner products $\langle\cdot\rangle_1$, $\langle\cdot\rangle_2$, and the two orthogonal complement bundles $C_1,~C_2$ to $F$ they define. There are canonical isomorphisms as follows: consider the restriction to $C_2$ of the projection onto $C_1$ parallel to $F$. This gives you an isomorphism $C_2\rightarrow C_1$, and similarly in the other direction. These are actually inverse to one another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** First show that for an inner product space $(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ and a subspace $W \subseteq V$,
$$W^\perp \cong V/W.$$
Then, using the quotient bundle construction of the previous exercise (exercise 2), show that for a Euclidean vector bundle $E \longrightarrow X$ with sub-bundle $F$,
$$F^\perp \cong E/F.$$
Since $E/F$ is independent of the bundle metric, this will show that $F^\perp$ does not depend on the bundle metric (up to isomorphism).

Let me know if you want me to provide the details of the argument.

Comment: Thanks. I think I need a little more detail; I tried this already, and was unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

In the proof of proposition $1.3$ in Hatcher's book, there is the algorithm for finding the orthogonal complement to your $F$ with respect to a chosen inner product. If we were to choose another inner product, the computation will be different starting from the step of the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process. Namely, when we apply the Gram-Schmidt process to the sections $s_1,...,s_n$:
$$s_1'=s_1,$$
$$s_2'=s_2-\frac{\langle s_2,s_1\rangle}{\langle s_1,s_1\rangle}s_1,$$
$$s_3'=s_3-\frac{\langle s_3,s_1\rangle}{\langle s_1,s_1\rangle}s_1-\frac{\langle s_3,s_2\rangle}{\langle s_2,s_2\rangle}s_2,$$
$$...$$
we will have different $s_n'$ for $n>1$ when we use a different inner product, let's call them $s_n''$.

However, we can easily construct an isomorphism sending $s_n''$ to $s_n'$. For example, suppose $s_2'=s_2-k_1s_2$, $s_2''=s_2-k_2s_2$, then we can let $s_2''\to s_2'$ be defined by $x\mapsto \frac{k_1}{k_2}x+\frac{k_2-k_1}{k_2}s_2(x)$. Therefore, the bundles having sections $s_n''$ and $s_n'$ are isomorphic (lemma $1.1$).